# Short using ccxt

Tags: python, ccxt, python-bybit

i am trying to open and close short positions on ccxt Bybit using ccxt with python. I do not find any kind of information or examples about how to do this.

Does anyone know how to do that, or has any example on opening and closing short positions using ccxt over Bybit or Bybit request api?

Thank you so,so,so,so,so,so,so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
    Install the ccxt library:
pip install ccxt

Opening short position:-
import ccxt
import time

# Replace 'YOUR_API_KEY' and 'YOUR_SECRET' with your Bybit API key and secret
api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
api_secret = 'YOUR_SECRET'

exchange = ccxt.bybit({
    'apiKey': api_key,
    'secret': api_secret,
    'enableRateLimit': True,
})

symbol = 'BTC/USD'  # Replace with the trading pair you want to trade
quantity = 1.0  # Replace with the quantity you want to trade

# Market order to open a short position
order = exchange.create_market_sell_order(symbol, quantity)

# Sleep for a moment to allow the order to be processed
time.sleep(2)

# Fetch the order status
order_status = exchange.fetch_order(order['id'], symbol)
print(f"Short position opened: {order_status}")

closing short position:
close_order = exchange.create_market_buy_order(symbol, quantity)

# Sleep for a moment to allow the order to be processed
time.sleep(2)

# Fetch the order status
close_order_status = exchange.fetch_order(close_order['id'], symbol)

print(f"Short position closed: {close_order_status}")
```